# I want to query difference between first and second highest salary

Tags: sql, oracle

I already got the second-highest salary.

I would like to display: employee name, salary, department name, and the difference between the highest and second-highest salary.

Here is my current code.

```
select  max(SAL) SecondHighestSalary 
from EMP A, DEPT B
where SAL < (
  select max(A.SAL)
  from EMP A, DEPT B
  where A.DEPTNO = B.DEPTNO and B.LOC = 'New York'
);
```

Thanks

Comment: Use RANK() function

Comment: @CleanBold That would return `NULL` if 2 people are tied for the highest salary. You either want `DENSE_RANK` (if you want first and second highest salaries ignoring ties) or `ROW_NUMBER` (if you want first and second highest salaried people respecting ties).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `DENSE_RANK` (if you want highest two unique salary values) or `ROW_NUMBER` (if you want the salary of the two highest earning people regardless of ties) analytic functions and then use conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT MAX( CASE WHEN sal_rank = 1 THEN sal END )
         - MAX( CASE WHEN sal_rank = 2 THEN sal END ) AS sal_difference_ignore_ties,
       MAX( CASE WHEN sal_rownum = 1 THEN sal END )
         - MAX( CASE WHEN sal_rownum = 2 THEN sal END ) AS sal_difference_with_ties
FROM   (
  SELECT e.deptno,
         e.sal,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY e.sal DESC ) AS sal_rank,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY e.sal DESC ) AS sal_rownum
  FROM   emp e
         INNER JOIN dept d
         ON ( e.deptno = d.deptno )
  WHERE  d.loc = 'New York'
);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE emp ( deptno, sal ) AS
SELECT 1, 2000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 2000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 1000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1,  500 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1,  200 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1500 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,  200 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,  700 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE dept ( deptno, loc ) AS
SELECT 1, 'New York' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Beijing'  FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> SAL_DIFFERENCE_IGNORE_TIES | SAL_DIFFERENCE_WITH_TIES
> -------------------------: | -----------------------:
>                       1000 |                        0
> ```

---

Or, if you want all the departments:

```sql
SELECT deptno,
       MAX( CASE WHEN sal_rank = 1 THEN sal END )
         - MAX( CASE WHEN sal_rank = 2 THEN sal END ) AS sal_difference_ignore_ties,
       MAX( CASE WHEN sal_rownum = 1 THEN sal END )
         - MAX( CASE WHEN sal_rownum = 2 THEN sal END ) AS sal_difference_with_ties
FROM   (
  SELECT e.deptno,
         e.sal,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY e.deptno ORDER BY e.sal DESC ) AS sal_rank,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY e.deptno ORDER BY e.sal DESC ) AS sal_rownum
  FROM   emp e
         INNER JOIN dept d
         ON ( e.deptno = d.deptno )
)
GROUP BY deptno;SELECT deptno,
       MAX( CASE WHEN sal_rank = 1 THEN sal END )
         - MAX( CASE WHEN sal_rank = 2 THEN sal END ) AS sal_difference_ignore_ties,
       MAX( CASE WHEN sal_rownum = 1 THEN sal END )
         - MAX( CASE WHEN sal_rownum = 2 THEN sal END ) AS sal_difference_with_ties
FROM   (
  SELECT e.deptno,
         e.sal,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY e.deptno ORDER BY e.sal DESC ) AS sal_rank,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY e.deptno ORDER BY e.sal DESC ) AS sal_rownum
  FROM   emp e
         INNER JOIN dept d
         ON ( e.deptno = d.deptno )
)
GROUP BY deptno;
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> DEPTNO | SAL_DIFFERENCE_IGNORE_TIES | SAL_DIFFERENCE_WITH_TIES
> -----: | -------------------------: | -----------------------:
>      1 |                       1000 |                        0
>      2 |                        500 |                      500
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=aa9d4b6eeaa8896a9d0612c2de2a87a5)*

Comment: Thanks very useful answers.

Comment: Could you display that employee name and employee's salary at the same time with difference_salary there?  Thanks

Comment: @v3f2ex Select the name in the inner query and use `LISTAGG` with a `CASE` expression to filter on rank in the outer expression [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f1b890380ecea54a6b51abc4b39f9bfc).

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

Based on Scott's EMP table:

```
SQL> select ename, sal
  2  from emp
  3  order by sal desc;

ENAME             SAL
---------- ----------
KING             5001       --> highest salary
FORD             3000       --> Ford and Scott share the 
SCOTT            3000       --> 2nd highest salary
JONES            2975
BLAKE            2850
CLARK            2450
ALLEN            1600
TURNER           1500
MILLER           1300
WARD             1250
MARTIN           1250
ADAMS            1100
SMITH            1000
JAMES             950

14 rows selected.
```

Then you'd *rank* them and - using `LISTAGG` (to display all employees that share the same highest or second highest salary) - get the final result:

```
SQL> with temp as
  2    (select e.ename,
  3            e.sal,
  4            dense_rank() over (order by e.sal desc) rnk,
  5            d.dname
  6     from emp e join dept d on d.deptno = e.deptno
  7    )
  8  select listagg(case when rnk = 1 then ename ||' - '|| dname || ' ($' || sal ||')' end, ', ')
  9           within group (order by ename) highest,
 10         --
 11         listagg(case when rnk = 2 then ename ||' - '|| dname || ' ($' || sal ||')' end, ', ')
 12           within group (order by ename) second_highest,
 13         --
 14         max(case when rnk = 1 then sal end) -
 15         max(case when rnk = 2 then sal end) diff
 16  from temp t
 17  where t.rnk in (1, 2);

HIGHEST                        SECOND_HIGHEST                                           DIFF
------------------------------ -------------------------------------------------- ----------
KING - ACCOUNTING ($5001)      FORD - RESEARCH ($3000), SCOTT - RESEARCH ($3000)        2001

SQL>
```